# PHP SQL Output orderby change refreshes whole page

Tags: php, sql, google-maps

I have some PHP code that initially sends a query to order by name ascending. I have arrow glyphicons to select different values to sort by. The data is about meteorites, in the database there's columns for name, id, class, lat, lon,year, and mass. I have arrow buttons for the user to sort for name, mass, and year both ASC and DESC.

I have it so that when the user selects an arrow to sort by it loads the page with JQuery and in this example it's sort mass ascendingly. I have an array of valid inputs so there's no risk for SQL injection.

```
$("#massASC").click(function () {
     location.href = '?orderby=massASC';
});
```

My problem is that I have a Google maps div that refreshes I'm loading a new page.

Is there a way that I can only refresh the table data and not load a new page?

Answer (score 0):

yes, You need use AJAX:

```
<div id="data_sorted">
....
....
</div>

$("#massASC").click(function () {
     $.post('/getData.php', {orderBy: 'massASC'}, function(response) {
         $('#data_sorted').html(response.html);
     });
});
```

getData.php:

```
$orderBy = $_POST['orderBy'];
$sql = 'SELECT * from {the_table} order by ' . $orderBy;
$data = // Fetch the data the way you want using $sql query
$html = '';
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $html .= 'SOME HTML for current row';
}

return json_encode(array('html' => $html));
```

Comment: I tried what you stated but my table of data isn't being populated on the site. I have it as follows:

`<table id='data'></table>
<script>
$("#massASC").click(function () {
   // location.href = '?orderby=massASC';
    $.post('/getData.php', {orderby: 'massASC'}, function(response){
            $('#data').html(response.html);
        });
});`

then in the getData.php I have all the sorted things being sorted the same
`foreach($meteors AS $meteor=>$data) {
    $html=
        '{table data output}'
}
return json_encode(array('html' => $html));`